# Run a custom MapReduce Jar in Amazon Elastic Map Reduce against data from Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr

I have data in DynamoDB which I want to run mapreduce jobs against. I've found a lot of tutorials which involve using Hive to run SQL against the dynamoDB data in EMR, but for the task I'm trying to perform it will be very difficult to efficiently write my task as SQL and I would rather just write a custom map-reduce jar. Is this possible, or is it only possible to write Hive SQL to query dynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can query DynamoDB without Hive.

Amazon provides [APIs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) that will allow you to rad and write to DynamoDB. So instead of using Hive you could write your own MapReduce job - with your Mapper querying DynamoDB using this API.